# How to test issues in a local development environment that can only be introduced by clustering in production?

Tags: web-development, session, state, cluster

We recently clustered an application, and it came to light that because of how we're doing SSL offloading via the load balancer in production it didn't work right. I had to mimic this functionality on my local machine by SSL offloading Apache with a proxy, but it still isn't a 1-to-1 comparison. Similar issues can arise when dealing with stateful applications and sticky sessions. What would be the industry standard for testing this kind of production "black box" scenario in a local environment, especially as it relates to clustering?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be expensive and painful, but in the end you need to have a local "cluster".  Trying to simulate race conditions, contention and the like are very hard on a single PC (my interpretation of "local development environment").

From past experience I would suggest:

- Push very hard to get a production level cluster into your test/dev environment, You can scale back some to keep costs down, but the profile needs to be representative of your production environment.
- Get periodic (weekly?) refreshes of your production DB into your dev/test environment
- Instrument your code for high amounts of logging in this environment
- Implement remote debugging on this cluster as best you can given your particular language and deployment stack

I have used this strategy in the past and was able to identify the underlying bug.  Then I was able to develop locally and unit test locally before deploying the fix to the test cluster.

Comment: I was going to answer this way, but I have never worked with clusters, so I refrained. But the embedded world has similar issues. Try as you might to simulate the hardware, once you run on the real hardware there's always stuff that doesn't work as expected. I suspect the same goes for clusters and your only good option is to have a software lab setup to mimick the production environment. Maybe it can be done on the cheap with using lesser quality systems than production uses.

Comment: Agreed, simulation can only get you so far.  Some problems need to be worked on in the true environment, whether that be clustered, embedded or some other architecture...

Comment: While this is the optimum solution I do wonder about the cost effectiveness. Our network operations finally received the budget for a staging instance of our load balancer, but that was an expensive decision. I'm curious if there are open source load balancers that emulate their higher load professional counterparts. I know it still isn't entirely 1-to-1, but maybe a little closer?

Comment: You may be able to get away with cheaper replacements for some parts, but in the end, you are debugging a problem with a specific set of hardware/software and replacing any component may leave you unable to replicate.  Admittedly, a tough decision to make financially, but if this is a external product or an internal critical application, you will need this level of test environment sooner or later.  Cost effectiveness should take into account loss of business/functionality, if you can not properly provide support.

Comment: @BrianReindel As long as you have an environment where you can hash out these issues it shouldn't be that big a deal.  Staging could work as a long as they will let you get in there to test and fix these types of issues before they go public.

Comment: @BrianReindel Alas, if you're using a serious load balancer (_e.g._, F5's BIG-IP), there are no comparable low-cost options.  In our environments, we do both.  Our load-test env uses an F5 cast off from a production upgrade, while our QA and Dev environments use the Apache proxy method.

Comment: @RossPatterson Do you find that the Apache equivalent sheds significant light on *most* problems, or is it hit and miss?

Comment: @BrianReindel The Apache method is just barely enough for a developer to test.  For QA, it isn't good enough.